# Validation on file type in java, Stop executable file from uploaded into Database?

Tags: java, postgresql, owasp, java-security

I have added the basic check on file-type by getting the file extension
as these are all allowed file-type and rest are blocked.

```
  if (fileExtension.toLowerCase().equals("jpg") || fileExtension.toLowerCase().equals("png") || fileExtension.toLowerCase().equals("gif") || fileExtension.toLowerCase().equals("jpeg")) {
    return true;
    }
```

The the problem is if a hacker uploads a .exe file disguised as .jpg and **intercept this request and after validation check updates the .jpg to .exe then he might be able to execute this in database which is extremely dangerous as script will be get executed.**
So how to stop .exe to be uploaded

Comment: You will need to actually look at the file content by examining the first bytes of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to check the file content along the extension name. For this one may use third party library like apache-tika.
https://medium.com/@ericfossas/quick-tut-file-type-detection-apache-tika-13967d453f42

Comment: Fine. The content check is done by checking the first bytes of a file, the _magic cookie_. They differ per file type. But the link explains.

Comment: That library is in Java. You can use PL/Java, but that is cumbersome. Are there libraries in any other language, like C, Perl or Python?

Comment: Apache tika was helpful but the problem is if the attacker is on window's machine the .exe has content type :-  application/x-msdownload, on linux machine .sh (script file) has extension -: text/plain and other executable packages has extension type as (application/x-debian-package, application/x-rpm), with there magic bytes all different. So how can I stop attacker from any os to intercept request and upload executable files into my database?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue.

I created a white list of magic bytes and mime type that apache tika returned and added a check against them.
Thanks all for your help